# java replaceAll(regex, replacement) regex command

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I would like to know if anyone knows the regex command to remove the following

```
 name =
```

from the following

```
 name = wlr
```

leaving only

```
 wlr
```

these details are taken from a txt file but the name =  part can appear multiple times

So I was thinking something like this would work but it doesn't work properly

```
 String file_name = newLine3.replaceAll("name = ", "");
```

Comment: Could you post a complete example of your input?

Comment: some example for "but it doesnt work properly" ?

Comment: May be a space issue. try "name\\s*=\\s*"

Comment: Your code [works properly](http://ideone.com/Japae), the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work properly" as it seems to work for me.

Comment: @AlanF are there spaces in front of your string? If yes you should point that out clearly.

Comment: @AlanF I removed the last line of your question on purpose, see [this for example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/179508). Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String file_name = newLine3.replaceAll("name\\s+=\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String newLine3 = "name = wlr";
String fileName = newLine3.replaceAll("name = ", ""); //fileName = "wlr"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
String input = "name = wlr";
String file_name = newLine3.substring(input.indexof("=") + 1).trim();
```

Regex seems like overkill for this issue.