# How To Replace All Letters To Underscore in java and ignoring the blank space between them

Tags: java

```
String name = "my name is varun";

String hideingName = new String(new char[name.length()]).replace('\0', '_');

// __ ___ _ ____ :- this is the required result
```

Comment: blank space ? Yes just replace letter by underscore

Comment: [Regex to match only letters](//stackoverflow.com/q/3617797)

Comment: What about punctuation?

Comment: And your expected output is wrong, not enought '_', like there is only 3 in tn the second group

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java replaceAll(regex, replacement) regex command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139623/java-replaceallregex-replacement-regex-command)

Answer (score 2):

```
String name = "my name is varun";
String hideingName = name.replaceAll("\\S", "_");
```

This replaces all non-space characters with an underscore. Space characters also include new lines, tabs, etc.

To capture strictly characters that aren't the spacebar space, this would work:

```
String name = "my name is varun";
String hideingName = name.replaceAll("[^ ]", "_");
```

Answer (score 1):

use replaceAll with [a-zA-Z] to catch all letters:

```
String name = "my name is varun";

String hideingName = name.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "_");
```

Answer (score 1):

You juste need to replace all non-space (`\S`) character by an underscore (`_`)

```
String name = "my name is varun";
String hideingName = name.replaceAll("\\S", "_");
System.out.println(hideingName);   

//my name is varun
//__ ____ __ _____
```